# Getting ID based on what Title is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get what the id value of a div is based on another div class. I keep getting undefined on title_name and id_name but not class_name so I think it getElementsByTagName is wrong but all research keeps pointing back to it as the only way for it to use.

```
<div class="date">
<div class="status" id="s_1" title="11/11/1111">111111</div>
<div class="status" id="s_3" title="11/22/1111">33333</div>
<div class="status" id="s_2" title="11/11/3333">222222</div>
<div id="Foundbytitle" title="status"></div>
```

```
    $('.status').click(function () {
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    var title_name = document.getElementsByTagName("class_name");
    var id_name = $(title_name[0]).attr('id');
    alert(id_name);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mM7x/1/

The desired alert would be 'Foundbytitle' when any of the divs are clicked since they all share the same class name and the id name of the result.

Comment: Reading your code shows what your code is doing, but what is it *meant* to do? If you want `'Foundbytitle'` you might as well just use `alert(this.id)`; but I have no idea what this is intended to do (nor why you'd go to such lengths to return the `id` of the element you're clicking).

Comment: Are you trying to get class, title and id of the element you are clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $('.status').click(function () {
        alert($('.'+$(this).attr('id')).attr('id'));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mM7x/4/

Or alternatively since the id is "foundbytitle" this is how to find it by title

```
$('.status').click(function () {
    alert($("div[title='"+$(this).attr('class')+"']").attr('id'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mM7x/10/

Comment: The alternative did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Awesome. Mark it as answered if you could. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.status').click(function () {
   var q = this.id;
   alert( $('.' + q).attr('id') );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mM7x/8/ (Try clicking 222222)